# How to log sessions with ssh.exe, similar to how PuTTY does full session logging

Tags: command-line, ssh, git, putty, conemu

I have installed Git for Windows and I use the built-in SSH client (OpenSSH 6.6.1p1) in ConEmu for tabbed SSH sessions.  It works very well, but I would like to have full session logging, like what is available in PuTTY.  I've read the man pages and I've tried using the -E argument for logging, but this seems like it's only error logging, and not session logging.  Does anyone have a solution or should I just set up ConEmu with PuTTY and be done with it?  I'm guessing to replicate the ease of use I would create a batch file somewhere named ssh.bat and use that to call the ConEmu/PuTTY command to attach it into a tab.  Anyone have ideas?

Comment: https://conemu.github.io/en/SettingsFeatures.html#id2679

Answer (score 0):

Did you try `-vvv` arguments? This works in normal openSSH, so I don't see the reason why it wouldn't work on Windows.

Comment: Yes, I've tried -vvv and -o LogLevel=DEBUG3 and it only logs debugging information about the connection, not any output from the session.

Comment: what log would you expect from the session? If you want transcript of session, you should use *nix `script` tool. You can let it start automatically as `ssh remote script /tmp/test;bash`

Comment: As mentioned in the original post, this is regarding ssh.exe included in Git for Windows, and the OS is Windows 7.  What I want is a transcript of the session, similar to PuTTY session logging.